# can we flatten the list produced by Map function which returns a list for every iteration in python

Tags: python

I'm writing a function which expands the list and returns a list. I may need to call this on a nested list so i wrote a function and calling that function using map statement for every items in the list. the map fucntions returns a list whose output i wanted to flatten it ..

I wrote the code as below:

```
def expandlist(a):
    if '-' in a:
        c = a.split('-')
        return [x for x in range(int(c[0]),int(c[1])+1)]
    else:
        return a
    
a = ['101-110', '113', '141-151']
d = list(map(expandlist,[x for x in a]))
print(d)
```

which returns out a list but i'm not sure how to flatten it.

```
[[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110], '113', [141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151]]
```

I wrote another piece of code to flatten the list which works fine but just wondering if the output of map statement can be leveraged to flatten the list

the other portion of the problem here is:
i wrote a fucntion to flatten the list :

```
flat_list1 = []
for sublist in d:
    if isinstance(sublist,list):
        for item in sublist:
            flat_list1.append(item)
    else:
        flat_list1.append(sublist)
print(flat_list1)
```

This works fine but when i try to achieve this using list comprehension, i get the below output:

```
[101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, '113', '113', '113', 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151]
```

in which 113 is repeated . am i missing anything here?

kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the list of expanded lists and extend them to a new list.

```
list.extend()
```

takes list and extend the existing list

Check documentation https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

```
    
    def expandlist(a):
        if '-' in a:
            c = a.split('-')
            return [x for x in range(int(c[0]),int(c[1])+1)]
        else:
            return [int(a)]

    a = ['101-110', '113', '141-151']
    d=[]
    s=list(map(expandlist,[x for x in a]))
    for i in s:
        d.extend(i)
    print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could flat your example format list with the following function:

```py
def expandlist(a):
    whole_list = []
    for sub_list in a:
        if "-" in sub_list:
            c = sub_list.split('-')
            whole_list.extend([x for x in range(int(c[0]), int(c[1]) + 1)])
        else:
            whole_list.append(int(sub_list))
    return whole_list
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes that will make your code more pythonic and faster.

```
def expandlist(a):
    if "-" in a:
        c = a.split("-")
        # return [x for x in range(int(c[0]), int(c[1]) + 1)]
        return range(int(c[0]), int(c[1]) + 1)
    else:
        # return a
        return int(a)


a = ["101-110", "113", "141-151"]

flat_list = []
# d = list(map(expandlist,[x for x in a]))
# print(d)
# for sublist in d:
for sublist in map(expandlist, a):
    
    # if isinstance(sublist,list):
    if isinstance(sublist, range):
        # for item in sublist:
        #     flat_list1.append(item)
        flat_list.extend(sublist)
    else:
        flat_list.append(sublist)

print(flat_list)
```